# Using enum list as methods with delegate

Tags: c#, enums, delegates

I'm trying to list some of my class' methods in an enum so that I can call these methods depending on the enum selected.  I tried using ToString() and GetMethod(string) with no luck.  If there's a better way to dynamically change which method my delegate will call from the list of enums I'd appreciate the help!  I'm very new to C#, and I'm also wondering if there are alternative ways of storing method pointers.  I looked into reflection on these boards and wasn't having much luck in either casting or assigning from enums.

```
public enum funcEnum { FirstFunction, SecondFunction };

public funcEnum eList;

public delegate void Del();

public Del myDel;


void Start() {

    myDel = FirstFunction; //pre-compiled assignment

    myDel(); //calls 'FirstFunction()' just fine
```

this below could be changed during runtime, it isn't normally going to be in Start()

```
    eList = funcEnum.SecondFunction; //this could be changed during runtime

    myDel = eList.ToString();
```

obvious error, myDel looking for method, not sure how I can retrieve/convert enum value to method to be assigned to the delegate, trying to call a method with having prior knowledge of assignment.  Basically wanting the enum list to contain names of methods within this class.

```
    myDel(); //doesn't work

}


public void FirstFunction() {

    Debug.Log("First function called");

}

public void SecondFunction() {

    Debug.Log("Second function called");

}
```

Comment: I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply assign a string to a method / delegate. Instead of this:

```
myDel = eList.ToString();
```

You can use the [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Delegate.CreateDelegate.aspx) method.

Something like this would for work instance methods:

```
myDel = (Del)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del), this, eList.ToString());
```

Or this for static methods:

```
myDel = (Del)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del), this.GetType(), eList.ToString());
```

Note I've assumed in both cases the methods are defined on the same class that's invoking the code. You'd have to modify this a bit to call methods on another object.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you...I didn't know anything about Delegate.CreateDelegate() and was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user2183858 There are a number of other ways to do this, but I think this requires minimal changes to the rest of your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you're interested is to use Reflection via [`MethodInfo`](http://www.en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3a_How_call_a_method_using_a_name_string):

```
var method = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod(eList.ToString());
method.Invoke(new YourClass(), null);
```

Comment: I tested this, which works well on it's own, but I'd be assigning the delegate like this: `myDel = method;` , in this case doesn't work (casting error).  Any suggestions then on casting MethodInfo to Del?

Comment: I figured you'd be okay with executing the method on the spot. But if you want to store it in a delegate, p.s.w.g's code is better.